# Java Nashhorn New Line

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I have a problem with the Java Nashhorn engine. New Lines (\n) do not working.

**Example:**

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval("print('test \n')");
```

**This is the error output:**

```
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:12 Missing close quote
```

**Thanks for helping**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `\`. Otherwise the effective javascript looks like:

```
print('test 
')
```

Which is incorrect.

Use this:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval("print('test \\n')");
```